# Is it possible to set env vars for containerd?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containerd

I am currently trying to switch my K8 nodes from using `dockerd` to `containerd`. For environment-specific reasons, I ned to specify `http_proxy`.

In the `dockerd` world, I can specify environment variables by using the following steps.

1. Putting lines such as the following into `/etc/environment-systemd`:

```
http_proxy=http://dns_name_of_my_proxy
```

2. Adding the following line to `/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service`:

```
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/environment-systemd
```

**How can I do the equivalent operation for containerd?**

I looked at the [man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man5/containerd-config.toml.5.html) for containerd's config and did not see any thing about setting environment variables for proxies.

Comment: It [certainly seems](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/issues/1990#issuecomment-403414959) the same `EnvironmentFile` trick should work, although it's possible containerd needs the variable to be uppercase and likely needs to be `HTTPS_PROXY=` if your upstream registry is over TLS (I always recommend setting them both to the same value since the good thing about standards ...)

Comment: @mdaniel There is no `Service` section documented in the man page. Is that issue referring to a different configuration file for `containerd`?

Comment: You can set environment variables in a service’s containers with the environment attribute in your Compose file. It works in the same way as docker run **-e VARIABLE=VALUE ...**. See how to [Use the environment attribute](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/#use-the-environment-attribute) for details.

Comment: Refer to official k8s doc on how to [Configure the kubelet to use containerd as its container runtime](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/migrating-from-dockershim/change-runtime-containerd/#configure-the-kubelet-to-use-containerd-as-its-container-runtime). If your using Amazon EKS, See [how to configure HTTP proxy for Amazon EKS containerd nodes](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/eks-http-proxy-containerd-automation) for details.

Comment: @VeeraNagireddy The second link addressed my question. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear that @merlin2011. Posting it as an answer for better community visibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to [How to automate HTTP proxy configuration for Amazon EKS containerd nodes](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/eks-http-proxy-containerd-automation) for more information.

Comment: Accepting this answer because it addresses the question.
I should note that the Stackoverflow community prefers to have the content directly in the answer (vs a link-only answer), but I do not know much about the ServerFault community.